# How to configure and execute Azure Devops classic editor pipeline after commit in Github?

Tags: github, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a Github and Azure Devops **classic editor pipeline**. I want to configure an auto-trigger of Azure pipeline after a commit happened in Github (If any commit happens in the repository, it needs to trigger my Azure Devops pipeline)

I tried configuring Continuous Integration in pipeline level, and it does not trigger my pipeline after a Github commit.

Many documents are for yaml pipeline but we need for classic editor pipeline. Could someone provide your inputs on how can we achieve the same ? Thanks!

Comment: In the "Get Sources" step do you use GitHub?

Comment: Yes I am using my service connection where my github is configured with Personal Access Token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration of @Bayoudhi Bilel is correct, after you select the Github as resource for Class editor pipeline, enable CI trigger in "Triggers" tab. (official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#ci-triggers))

Check on my side, it works fine:
[image]

If your setting doesn't work, please firstly check if you have select correct branch to monitor. If it's correct, you can follow below steps to reconnect between azure devops and github repo.

1. Delete all webhooks on github repo setting.
   [image]
2. Then edit your pipeline, go to "Triggers" tab, "restore" the webhook.
   [image]
3. change to a new service connection(it's recommended to regenerate the github [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#permissions-needed-in-github-2), you can simply add all scope):
   [image]

Comment: Could you please help me by providing a sample URL to be used to github webhooks for this ? I have configured URL as "https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview" and I face issue as "Last delivery was not successful invalid http response 400".

Comment: You should not setup the webhook manually, when you choose the github repo as resource and setup and pipeline, it will automatically create the webhook for you. The URL in my github repo setting: https://github.com/{ado_org}/{githubreponame}/settings/hooks/3135x9x287.

Comment: This works fine for me for Github. But for Github Enterprise Server its not working, any inputs on how to perform for GHE ?

Comment: @Kivi, is your Github Enterprise server reachable from the servers that run Azure Pipelines service? If it's not, you cannot configure CI or PR triggers for your classic build pipelines. Please refer to offiical doc below for the details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github-enterprise?view=azure-devops. If it helps, please kindly mark it, thanks.

Comment: @Kivi, greetings, how is it going? is it resolved? let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for CI/CD triggers, you can simply choose the proper branch in the build trigger combo box.

"In the classic editor, pipeline triggers are called build completion triggers. You can select any other build in the same project to be the triggering pipeline.

After you add a build completion trigger, select the triggering build. If the triggering build is sourced from a Git repo, you can also specify branch filters. If you want to use wildcard characters, then type the branch specification (for example, features/modules/*) and then press Enter."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers-classic?view=azure-devops

if you are looking for deployment triggers you can find more info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops

[release trigger snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSjdM.png)

Comment: @Bilel, thanks for your reply. This document does not contain the configuration for git commit auto-trigger and it explains about Trigger 1 pipeline after another and it is for Release pipeline. Could you please suggest the ways for Build pipeline trigger according to Git commit ?

Answer (score 0):

In my Azure devops, i did it by going to pipeline > Triggers tab and i activated "Enable continous integration". You can also configure the branches you want to build from.
It worked for me this way.
Please find screenshot attached.

[image: build trigger]

Comment: This is the same way I have tried, but after a commit it is not triggering the pipeline. Have you tried it from Classic editor pipeline or from Yaml pipeline ?

Comment: I tried from the classic editor not yaml. It looks like that i could not reproduce the issue from my side because it have worked fine for me. Could you please recheck that you have used the correct repo and included the proper branches and commiting changes to the selected ones.